# Angularjs filter on two values of one field

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I need to use either a filter or another, how to do?

```
<tr ng-repeat="currentCollectionItem in binding 
               | filter: ({ isPending: false } || {isPending: undefined})">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You can do this using only one condition:

```
filter:'!true'
```

This is how you can apply false and undefined properties.

## Example

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-filter-filter-production</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="">
<div ng-init="binding = [{name:'John', isPending:false},
                         {name:'Mary', isPending:false},
                         {name:'Mike', isPending:undefined},
                         {name:'Adam'},
                         {name:'Julie', isPending:true},
                         {name:'Juliette', isPending:true}]"></div>

<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>isPending</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="currentCollectionItem in binding | filter:'!true'">
    <td>{{ currentCollectionItem.name }}</td>
    <td ng-show="{{currentCollectionItem.isPending !== undefined}}">{{ currentCollectionItem.isPending }}</td>
    <td ng-show="{{currentCollectionItem.isPending === undefined}}">undefined</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom predicate function:

```
<tr ng-repeat="currentCollectionItem in binding | filter: notPendingFilterFn">
```

```
$scope.notPendingFilterFn = function(value, index, array) {
     return value.isPending === false || value.isPending === undefined;
};
```

A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of the array, with the element, its index, and the entire array itself as arguments.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `filter` Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Can you do it without this predicate function? Checking filter in html?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to define a filter method on your controller/component class and use that instead.

This has two main advantages:

1. Easier to unit test - you can call the function on your controller/component instance directly to test the filter logic.
2. Simpler markup/keeps the complicated code where it belongs, in the JS.

If you need help doing this, let me know.

Comment: I need to put in own html, you know how to do it like this?

Comment: @DanielleRodrigues What do you mean by "put in own html"?

Comment: I need to check the filter in the html itself, as it is in the code I put. I would not like to filter on the controller / component class

Comment: @DanielleRodrigues I'm curious why you cannot place this filter method on the controller/component class. Doing so is considered better practice than having complicated logic in the view (template). Why is it necessary to disregard this best practice in your case?